# Force left to right in UIPageViewController under iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, right-to-left

I'm using `UIPageViewController` in my application and since iOS9 was published, while I'm on RTL languages, my `UIPageViewController` has changed its direction to RTL.

I want to force the `UIPageViewController` to always be LTR, even if the system language is RTL.

Using Semantic LTR in storyboard didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .ForceLeftToRight
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

You can use it in `Appdelegate.swift` file under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` event.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for setting semantic content attributes on view controllers. You are welcome to file an enhancement request for this via bugreport.apple.com.

You can also continue to use an earlier version of Xcode and compile against the 8.x SDK. This will disable all RTL behaviors introduced in iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the `viewDidLoad()` delegate method:

```
self.pageViewController!.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```